# Trying to rename a file and get a Value Error

Tags: python, rename, valueerror

I get the ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)    on line 16. any tips on what I did wrong?

Main func()

```
def main():
    i = 1

    import os
    path = "C:\\State_K-1_Info_Manual\\3-Partner_K-1s\\"

    for filename in os.listdir("C:\\State_K-1_Info_Manual\\3-Partner_K-1s\\"):
        prefix, num = filename[:-3].split('_')
        num = num.zfill(4)
        new_filename = prefix + "_" + num + ".pdf"
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_filename))

    for filename in os.listdir("C:\\State_K-1_Info_Manual\\3-Partner_K-1s\\"):
        dst1 = str(i) + ".pdf"
        dst = dst1.zfill(7)
        src = 'C:\\State_K-1_Info\\3-Partner_K-1s_Manual\\' + filename
        dst = 'C:\\State_K-1_Info\\3-Partner_K-1s_Manual\\' + dst

        # rename() function will
        # rename all the files
        os.rename(src, dst)
        i += 1


# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Calling main() function
    main()
```

Comment: what is line 16?

Comment: check your `filename` in the first loop, are you sure it contains an underscore?

Comment: Post the full traceback. It contains more useful info than you think.

Comment: We need the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rbonnes/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/Rename_k1s.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/rbonnes/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/Rename_k1s.py", line 16, in main
    prefix, num = filename[:-3].split('_')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the line:

```py
prefix, num = filename[:-3].split('_')
```

You need to make sure the array resulting from the expression on the right has exactly 2 elements in order to unpack it to `prefix` and `num`.